# C# WPF - Acessar elemento de outra XAML por codigo

Tags: c#, wpf

Olá, tenho  duas telas uma Window e uma Page carregada dentro da tela

```
Class Window1{
   //to do ..
 __mainFrame; // acessa normal
}

Class page1{
 //to do
__mainFrame; // sem  acesso ao frame
}
```

Dentro da classe window tenho um  **`<Frame x:Name="__mainFrame"></frame>`** a onde carrego as paginas e queria quando clicasse em  um botão que esteja dentro de **`page1`** fosse carregado nesse iframe como  os dois estão em classes diferentes não estou  conseguindo carregar, teria alguma forma de fazer esse acesso ?

Obs, utilizar o extend de uma classe dentro da outra não funciona
Como  no exemplo abaixo

```
Class window1 : page1{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom consegui  aqui  a forma para fazer isso

```
Class page1{

((Window1)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).__mainFrame;

}
```

A onde Window é o nome da classe da minha **Window1** que referencia o xmal que quero acessar  e **MainWindow** é o  **x:Name** do elemento window

desta forma  pode-se acessar qualquer elemento externo a sua classe

Answer (score 1):

A forma como você fez resolve o problema, mas em um ambiente com várias classes e múltiplos níveis de objetos você terá problemas de referência. Fora o acoplamento entre as classes que vai só crescer, se você precisar mudar o nome **__mainFrame** em algum momento, terá que sair mudando em vários arquivos. Enfim, a manutenção vai ficar extremamente complexa.

Uma solução melhor (existe outras, com certeza), é você criar uma propriedade do tipo Action na sua page1, atribuir uma função à ela na sua Windows1 e depois executar na page1 quando precisar.

Exemplo:

```
Class Window1{

    construtor(){
        // crie uma instancia de page1 ou acesse uma já existente, como exemplo, vou criar
        var page1 = new page1();
        page1.FazerAlgumaCoisa = () => {
            __mainFrame; // aqui você tem acesso ao objeto __mainFrame para fazer o que quiser      
        }
    }  
    __mainFrame; // acessa normal
}

Class page1{
    public Action FazerAlgumaCoisa { get; set;}

    public void ExecutarAcaoNoMainFrame(){

        this.FazerAlgumaCoisa?.Invoke();

    }
}
```

Você também pode passar parâmetros se necessário, basta alterar a sua propriedade Action, como no exemplo abaixo onde passo uma string.

```
Class Window1{

    construtor(){
        // crie uma instancia de page1 ou acesse uma já existente, como exemplo, vou criar
        var page1 = new page1();
        page1.FazerAlgumaCoisa = (parametro1) => {
            __mainFrame; // aqui você tem acesso ao objeto __mainFrame para fazer o que quiser      
//parametro1 pode ser usada aqui
        }
    }  
    __mainFrame; // acessa normal
}

Class page1{
    public Action<string> FazerAlgumaCoisa {get;set;}

    public void ExecutarAcaoNoMainFrame(){

        this.FazerAlgumaCoisa?.Invoke("qualquer valor");

    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, agora eu estou  fazendo de uma forma  um pouco diferente utilizando uma classe controladora de instancia assim evetia que haja eventuais crashing por arquivos não intanciado então fica public static TipoPage NomeAcess; ai faço a verificação se o arquivo está instanciado e chamo por ele